# What is the difference between locate --basename and locate --wholename on Linux?

Tags: command-line, locate

On the manual page of `locate`, I read this:

```
locate --basename
    Match only the base name against the specified patterns. 
    This is the opposite of --wholename.
```

but I don't get it. What does it mean? What is the difference between `locate --basename` and `locate --wholename`? Can you give me some simple examples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basename is the *last* part of the full path

```
/etc/default/grub
              ^
             basename
```

By default `locate` matches a pattern *anywhere* in the path.

With `-b` (basename) it matches only paths where the pattern appears in the last part of the pathname, the filename or directory name itself.

For example, output from `locate gimp` would include

```
/etc/gimp
/etc/gimp/2.0
/etc/gimp/2.0/controllerrc
```

And *many* other things, but `locate -b gimp` would find

```
/etc/gimp
```

Without including the subdirectories, since there is no `gimp` string in their basenames.